# Mas de 2 lineas en un input

Tags: html, css, vscode

Alguien sabe como hacer mas de 2 lineas en un input de tipo texto? Me pasa que solo es un renglon de carácter infinito y no me deja darle a enter+shift para continuar abajo. Como hago para solucionarlo? Para poder escribir en mas de 1 renglon en html o cssvscode!

Comment: ¿Podrías dar mas detalles por favor?

Comment: Hola Agustin, bienvenido, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida y obtengas una mejor respuesta, y evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla! te recomiendo que edites tu pregunta y agregues el código de tu aplicación.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar un **Text Area**, dependiendo el tamaño del contenedor y la longitud del contenido se ira desplazando.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>TextArea</h1>

  <form action="/action_page">
    <textarea id="" name="" rows="4" cols="50">Contenidoooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo</textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Dime si te sirvió.